# Apt install can't find a package that apt search easily finds

Tags: apt, 22.04

I've got a weird apt bug here on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I'm trying to install `containerd.io` as part of [a Kubernetes walkthrough](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/#3_Install_Containerd_Runtime) (Why do package names include periods?! What's the difference between `containerd` and `containerd.io`? But I digress) and I can find the package just fine with `apt search` but `apt install` feigns ignorance of it:

```
$ apt search containerd.io
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
containerd.io/jammy 1.6.26-1 amd64
  An open and reliable container runtime

$ sudo apt install -y containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
```

I have their repo key and record installed properly:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ | grep -v ubuntu
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3817 Dec 22 23:19 docker.asc
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list 
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
```

`apt update` runs without a hitch:

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
49 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

So my question is: why is `search` finding the package while `install` isn't?

Comment: Which is your default arch I see ports.ubuntu.com

Comment: I’m away from it right now, but it should be an `amd64` VM on an `arm64` host using QEMU.  If the VMs are somehow `arm64` then I’ll have to junk and rebuild the VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM had the wrong architecture, and `containerd.io` apparently isn't available for `arm64`.